# Networking between VMs on VMware Workstation

Tags: php, networking, vmware, vmware-workstation

I've set up two virtual machines on one VMware Workstation. How to configure it to communicate with one another (two way).

For example, if VM #1 is running php web server and if it gets the IP address 192.168.1.12, the browser on VM #2 should be able to access `http://192.168.1.12`.

I couldn't figure out the exact solution. I saw that it depends on the Network type. Please guide me how to set it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three basic types of networks supported in vmware player and virtualbox. 
1) HOST ONLY
2) NAT
3) BRIDGE

and there are other variations of these.

Since your question in specific to vmware, the answer will go specific to it.

FOR ur problem NAT network will be fine.
1)NAT
Using NAT the VMs will get 192.168.211.0/24 network. (At least this happens in my case)
In this 192.168.211.1 will be the IP of the Host machine. 
192.168.211.2 will be a dedicated IP. The vmware workstation internally uses this IP. The nameserver ,gateway and DHPC Server IP address will be 192.168.211.2. (All three same)

Now when u setup guests machines the DHCP Server will assign the ip addresses to these machines.

Next if you are running PHP server on 192.168.211.12(say) then go to this machine and change the interface file for this machine and assign static IP 192.168.211.12 to this machine. 
There are hundred of documents available on how to configure interface file. 
ex:-

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=static   //or set this as NONE
ONBOOT=yes
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
IPADDR=192.168.211.12
GATEWAY=192.168.211.2
```

NOTE:- IN vmware the NAT network allows inter VMs communication as well internet connectivity. 
Using NAT in case of virtualbox does not allow inter Vms communication, it only allows internet connectivity.
NAT network works even in offline mode.

2) BRIDGE
In bridge mode the VMs are assigned IP from the same network as your physical LAN. Don't use it if u are not administrator of the LAN. 
Bridge mode works in only in online mode.

3) HOST only allows inter VMs communication but creates local network between VMs and does not provides internet connectivity. You will have to configure one more interface in NAT mode for internet connectivity. (I used to do this when i use virtual box. i.e configure one interface in host only mode and another in NAT mode, since to make bridge mode work in virtual box is painful ).

These are some useful links

1) http://blog.pluralsight.com/vm-workstation-advanced-networking:- U can read this article if u want to understand how HOST machine adapters are configured.

2) http://pibytes.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/vmware-workstation-networking-basics/:- This blog is pretty good to understand how different modes work.

Answer (score 2):

first of all are you using bridged network settings in vmware ?

if yes excellent if not i suggest you do, that way the host and the virtual machine will get different ip address.

i hate just posting links but i cant explain it any better my self with out plagiarising 
https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-D9B0A52D-38A2-45D7-A9EB-987ACE77F93C.html

after they have different ip address on your local network we can move on next step,

then look to see what ip the host and the virtual machine has windows this can be done with ipconfig and in linux\unix ifconfig

step 2 (optional) i suggest you setup a static ip for the machine you want to access (this is assuming you will be using it often if you intend to delete this vm in a few hours might not be worth it)

depending on your network setup this can usually be achieved by your router in DHCP settings and entering the mac address assigned to the virtual machine (this can be found on the network settings of vmware workstation its self) with a static ip address of your choice with in your range (default is usually 192.168.1.0-255) i cant guide you through this in detail as every routers UI is different

if you have your own dhcp server well then im preaching the preaching to the choir :) and im sure you know how to setup a static ip.

end of step 2

after that is setting up the web server part and i think that may be another question all together as we dont even know the os's you are running and what type of server you want (Apache/IIS) etc the possibility are endless so listing them would take considerably time  but this should at least allow you to ping both of them from each other meaning they can communicate :) if you want help configuring the webserver or anything else feel free to message me il do my best to answer